hosting websites on two different servers from one public Ip
So i'm looking at hosting two websites on separate servers For example: Production site on the IIS server: 192.168.0.1 and SpecialApps IIS: 192.168.0.2 which is also the current test server which will eventually go into production.
Currently after countless hours of research, it been suggested that I should install Application Request Routing (ARR), which I had done so on the .2 server
my goal is to be able to go https://test.mycompany.com.au to go into .2 and https://test.mycompany.com.au/prod to go to .1
when the user go https://test.mycompany.com.au/prod, need to redirect to https://mycompany.com.au which is the production url that is hosted on .1
Having issues trying to get the URL Rewrite code pattern working
Is this even viable?

In general people access production and test systems by unique DNS names, ie they use www.example.com for prod and for example  designate test.example.com for test  ; in the case of web applications and websites that allows you to deploy content in the root and prevents the complicated workarounds and URL and content rewriting that is often required to make both non-prod and prod of the same sites and applications available on the name DNS hostname.

Those requirements sound contradictory. Either https://test.mycompany.com.au/prod is proxied to another server as-is or it redirects the client to a different URL; how would it work with both? (Yes, the webapp itself could redirect, but that's not what you're configuring...)

This question is similar to: Multiple Websites on Multiple Servers behind One Public IP. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If the sites are going to share the same public hostname (test.mycompany.com.au) or IP but live on separate internal servers, then yes you'll need a service like ARR to intercept and redirect requests based on the logic you specify. This function is usually called a "reverse proxy" and ARR supports it
Take a look through this MS walkthrough doc for detailed configurations and examples: Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing. The basic idea is your ARR rules should default to the local test IIS site and redirect /prod requests to the main server (based on the setup you've described)
